# Open an external file with a button on a form in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, button

I am creating a database for my Unit (I am in the Army) and I need a button that will launch a file when clicked.  The file is a .xfdl file used for military forms in a program called PureEdge.  Is this possible and how would I go about doing it.  I have searched it as much as I know how, but it seems that my Google-Fu is failing me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If the file type is associated with the program, that is, the file will launch when clicked, then [FollowHyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa204494%28v=office.10%29.aspx) may suit, otherwise, you may need to use Shell. For example:

```
Call Shell("""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\msaccess.exe"" ""c:\docs\db.mdb""", vbNormalFocus)
```