# Access - Add button to open external file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to make a button which will open a file on disk. But I'm doing something wrong - my code throws an error and I need help with it.

I saw this topic: [Open an external file with a button on a form in Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925380/open-an-external-file-with-a-button-on-a-form-in-access-2007) but in that solution the first argument of this statement is the path to .exe of the program which I want to use. Problem is that I am using a company computer and I can not find NOTEPAD.EXE or Acrobat Reader 2017 (should I type another thing)?

```
Private Sub Polecenie45_Click()
    Call Shell("""C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Acrobat Reader 2017.exe"" ""C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\p1.pdf""", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

When I click the button I want to open my external file - for example (on this case) a pdf file with some pictures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I open a file with VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438422/how-do-i-open-a-file-with-vbscript)

Comment: You don't need to know where Acrobat Reader is located. Simply use `WScript.Shell.Run` on the document, see link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iv'e found it once somewhere on the web, can't recall where. Iv'e put it in a it's own module, and use by calling `OpenFile`, passing in a full file path as a parameter.
Here:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Function OpenFile(sFileName As String)
On Error GoTo Err_OpenFile

    OpenFile = ShellExecute(Application.hWndAccessApp, "Open", sFileName, "", "C:\", 1)

Exit_OpenFile:
    Exit Function

Err_OpenFile:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_OpenFile

End Function
```

This module came with the test. you can run it:

```
Public Function TestOpeningFile()
On Error GoTo Err_TestOpeningFile

    OpenFile "C:\Windows\Win.ini"' Replace this line with any file 

Exit_TestOpeningFile:
    Exit Function

Err_TestOpeningFile:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_TestOpeningFile

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks mate for help.